# Python nose processes parameter and dynamically generated tests

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing, nose

I have the minimal working example below for dynamically generating test cases and running them using `nose`.

```py
class RegressionTests(unittest.TestCase):
    """Our base class for dynamically created test cases."""

    def regression(self, input):
        """Method that runs the test."""

        self.assertEqual(1, 1)


def create(input):
    """Called by create_all below to create each test method."""

    def do_test(self):
        self.regression(input)
    return do_test


def create_all():
    """Create all of the unit test cases dynamically"""

    logging.info('Start creating all unit tests.')

    inputs = ['A', 'B', 'C']
    
    for input in inputs:

        testable_name = 'test_{0}'.format(input)
        testable = create(input)
        testable.__name__ = testable_name
        class_name = 'Test_{0}'.format(input)

        globals()[class_name] = type(class_name, (RegressionTests,), {testable_name: testable})
        logging.debug('Created test case %s with test method %s', class_name, testable_name)

    logging.info('Finished creating all unit tests.')


if __name__ == '__main__':

    # Create all the test cases dynamically
    create_all()

    # Execute the tests
    logging.info('Start running tests.')
    nose.runmodule(name='__main__')
    logging.info('Finished running tests.')
```

When I run the tests using `python nose_mwe.py --nocapture --verbosity=2`, they run fine and I get the output:

```
test_A (__main__.Test_A) ... ok
test_B (__main__.Test_B) ... ok
test_C (__main__.Test_C) ... ok
```

However, when I try to use the `processes` command line parameter to make the tests run in parallel, e.g.  `python nose_mwe.py --processes=3 --nocapture --verbosity=2`, I get the following errors.

```
Failure: ValueError (No such test Test_A.test_A) ... ERROR
Failure: ValueError (No such test Test_B.test_B) ... ERROR
Failure: ValueError (No such test Test_C.test_C) ... ERROR
```

Is there something simple that I am missing here to allow the dynamically generated tests to run in parallel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as far as I can tell you just need to make sure that `create_all` is run in every test process.  just moving it out of the `__main__` test works for me, so the end of the file would look like:

```py
# as above

# Create all the test cases dynamically
create_all()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Execute the tests
    logging.info('Start running tests.')
    nose.runmodule(name='__main__')
    logging.info('Finished running tests.')
```

Comment: Thanks Sam, when I make that change the tests run with 3 processes. However, I see the creation of the tests happening twice i.e. the debug log `Created test case ...` appears twice for each test case. It looks like `create_all` is called twice. Is there some way of preventing this?

Comment: think it's doing exactly what you tell it to do, i.e. running those tests in `n` processes... variables are not shared between processes, so to be able to get to those tests it needs to know about them, hence they need to be registered in each one.  what are you trying to avoid by trying to prevent this?

Comment: Thanks, I haven't much experience with Python and its unit test framework so I was naively expecting the parent process to create, and somehow register, the test cases once and then when `nose.runmodule` is called that the tests would be distributed among the child processes. Thanks again for the feedback, I will mark the question as answered.

Comment: no probs; I'm just going from general python knowledge and there might be something specific you could do to work around specific cases.  I'd also suggest trying to write a decorator for what you're trying to do, it makes it more obvious to the reader (and any automated tooling) where any global definitions are coming from